# Making n(%) tables using R: apply removes rownames

Tags: r, apply

Like many people, I need to able to make descriptive tables with n(%) formatting. I've written some R code (see below) that does this, and it almost works the way I hoped it would.

The main problem I have with the code is that the apply function strips the label and rownames for Gender from the frq table/matrix. I can and do put those back but wondered if there is some way to avoid this in the first place.

The approach I've taken to getting n(%) formatted output seems simple and direct but I'd also be interested in seeing other ways of getting the sort of output my code produces.

```
#### Sample data ####

rashData <-
structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"),
    RashGrp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gender",
"RashGrp"), row.names = c(NA, 207L), class = "data.frame")
```

Table code ####

```
frq <- with(rashData, table(Gender, RashGrp, dnn=c("Gender", "Rash")))
frq <- addmargins(frq, FUN = list(list(Total = sum)), quiet = TRUE)

den  <- which(rownames(frq)!= "Total")
npct <- function(x)
    paste(format(x), " (", format( x/sum(x[den])*100, digits=4, nsmall=2 ), "%)", sep="")

tablObj <- apply(frq, 2, npct)
names(dimnames(tablObj))[1] <- names(dimnames(frq))[1]
rownames(tablObj) <- rownames(frq)

tablObj
```

Comment: You should look at `sprintf`. It might simplify some of your `format` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: Skip the `apply` and simply pass the table object to npct with an assignment back to the object with `[]` to preserve structure:

```
frq <- with(rashData, table(Gender, RashGrp, dnn=c("Gender", "Rash")))
mfrq <- addmargins(frq, FUN = list(list(Total = sum)), quiet = TRUE)
npct <- function(x)
    paste(format(x), " (", format( x/sum(frq)*100, digits=4, nsmall=2 ), "%)", sep="")

mfrq[] <-  npct(mfrq)
mfrq
#----------------
        Rash
Gender   Yes            No             Total         
  Male    30 ( 14.493%)  85 ( 41.063%) 115 ( 55.556%)
  Female  12 (  5.797%)  80 ( 38.647%)  92 ( 44.444%)
  Total   42 ( 20.290%) 165 ( 79.710%) 207 (100.000%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm doing this the right way. Thought about revising my question instead. Simply supplying a proposed answer seemed a bit more natural though.

The three responses I received were all very helpful. Thomas's suggestion to use sprintf has allowed me to simplify my formatting code.

From James, I learned about the attributes function. As my original question shows, I've been accomplishing the work of this function using a combination of things like rownames, colnames, and names(dimnames()). Obviously, the attributes function is a lot quicker and so I'm glad to have learned about it.

DWin's response was also quite helpful. Applying the npct function in the way he suggests didn't produce the correct percentages. In retrospect, I wish I had included the output my code was producing in my original question. That would have made things clearer, and is something I'll need to be more careful about in the future. The use of [] he pointed out was quite valuable, and did make it's way into the proposed solution.

The proposed solution is pasted below. It uses apply even though James and Dwin weighed in against that. I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with the use of apply but would be open to feedback about that. I'd also be happy to receive any proposed improvements to the code.

Thanks,

Paul

```
#### Sample data ####

rashData <-
structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"),
    RashGrp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gender",
"RashGrp"), row.names = c(NA, 207L), class = "data.frame")

#### Table code ####

frq <- with(rashData, table(Gender, RashGrp, dnn=c("Gender", "Rash")))
frq <- addmargins(frq, FUN = list(list(Total = sum)), quiet = TRUE)
npct <- function(x) sprintf("%3.0f%s%*.2f%s", x, " (", 6, x/sum(x[rownames(frq)!="Total"])*100, "%)")
frq[] <- apply(frq, 2, npct)
frq

        Rash
Gender   Yes           No            Total        
  Male    30 ( 71.43%)  85 ( 51.52%) 115 ( 55.56%)
  Female  12 ( 28.57%)  80 ( 48.48%)  92 ( 44.44%)
  Total   42 (100.00%) 165 (100.00%) 207 (100.00%)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `paste`, not the `apply` call. However you can avoid `apply` by using `prop.table` and then copy over the `attributes` from `frq`:

```
fmtTbl <- paste0(format(frq), "(", format(rbind(prop.table(frq[den,],2)*100,rep(100,3)),
 digits=4, nsmall=2), "%)")
attributes(fmtTbl) <- attributes(frq)
fmtTbl
        Rash
Gender   Yes           No            Total        
  Male    30 ( 71.43%)  85 ( 51.52%) 115 ( 55.56%)
  Female  12 ( 28.57%)  80 ( 48.48%)  92 ( 44.44%)
  Total   42 (100.00%) 165 (100.00%) 207 (100.00%)
```